# When I am building my build.xml in ant I am getting two error messages below is snap:

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build.xml

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\workspace\Cq\build.xml:157: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\workspace\Cq\CqClient\build.xml:155: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 40 seconds
```

1. When we click to first link of error it goes to main build.xml below bold and italic line:

```xml
   <target name="build" description="Builds components necessary for CqServer" depends="prepare">
      <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${build.home.dir}/MCD_JavaClient" target="jar" inheritAll="true"/>
      <!--<ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${cqserver.dir}" target="jar" inheritAll="true"/>
      <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${cqclient.dir}" target="war" inheritAll="true"/>-->
      <ant dir="${cqserver.dir}" inheritAll="false"/>
      ***<ant dir="${cqclient.dir}" inheritAll="false"/>***on this line it shows error
   </target>
```

2. When I click to second link it shows the error in the build.xml of the client side:

```xml
<javac srcdir="${base.src}" debug="${debug}" deprecation="${deprecation}" destdir="${build.classes}"> 
            <classpath refid="classpath.base" /> 
</javac>
```

Error log:

```
[javac] C:\Users\workspace\Cq\CqClient\src\com\cq\j2ee\actions\AutoAction.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] import com.cq.j2ee.util.Constants;
[javac]                              ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Constants
[javac]   location: package com.cq.j2ee.util
[javac] C:\Users\workspace\Cq\CqClient\src\com\cq\j2ee\actions\AutoAction.java:21: error: package com.cq.j2ee.ejb does not exist
[javac] import com.cq.j2ee.ejb.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] C:\Users\workspace\Cq\CqClient\src\com\cq\j2ee\actions\AutoAction.java:22: error: package com.cq.j2ee.msg does not exist
[javac] import com.cq.j2ee.msg.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] C:\Users\workspace\Cq\CqClient\src\com\cq\j2ee\actions\AutoAction.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     private CqRemote cqRemote = null;
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class CqRemote
[javac]   location: class AutoAction

[javac] C:\Users\workspace\Cq\CqClient\src\com\cq\j2ee\actions\BulkUploadAction.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] import com.cq.j2ee.util.DtConverter;
[javac]                              ^
[javac]   symbol:   class DtConverter
[javac]   location: package com.cq.j2ee.util
[javac] C:\Users\workspace\Cq\CqClient\src\com\cq\j2ee\actions\BulkUploadAction.java:32: error: package com.cq.j2ee.vo does not exist
[javac] import com.cq.j2ee.vo.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] C:\Users\workspace\Cq\CqClient\src\com\cq\j2ee\actions\BulkUploadAction.java:33: error: package com.cq.j2ee.ejb does not exist
[javac] import com.cq.j2ee.ejb.*;
```

I have also set my path variable in system properties pointing to bin of my jdk, I have set my JAVA_HOME to C:\Program file\Java\JDK1.7.0_51.

Can anyone please help me out from this error.

Comment: *"Can anyone please help me out from this error."* - Not unless you show us the compiler errors!

Comment: I have added error log please have a look

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your CqClient doesn't see some your classes/packages. If they are in different project please try to add proper dependency in CqClient project. How to do it ? I'm using Netbeans and in this IDE I have to display properties of project and then go to Libraries and for Compile section select 'Add Project' or 'Add Library' and select project or library (jar file) which includes classes/packages that you need